# macOS sed - Complex substitution command

Tags: bash, macos, sed, text-parsing

I have a text file with a lot of lines and need to do some complex substitutions using macOS sed. It's a bit hard to explain my problem so I'll show you an example first:

The file:

```
#00101:A9AA%AAB
#03901:%E+2100009+X3800
#06008:01020304
```

Expected output:

```
#00101:0000%A00
#03901:%E+2000000+X0000
#06008:01020304
```

For all lines starting with "#xxx01:" (where x represents any digit), I need to replace all alphanumeric characters (A-Z, 0-9) with "0", except the numbers before the ":", and any two-character sequences starting with "%" or "+".

I am aware of the basic substitution and exception commands, as well as using "^" to search for a pattern at the start of a line, but I am confused as to how to combine all those commands. How should I go about doing this? Non-sed solutions are welcome if this is impossible in sed.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file `script.sed` containing:

```
/^#[0-9]{3}01:/ {
    :r
    s/:((0|[+%]..)*)[A-Za-z1-9]/:\10/
    t r
}
```

Call the file containing your sample input data `data`.
Run the command shown to get the required output:

```
$ sed -E -f script.sed data
#00101:0000%AA0
#03901:%E+0000000+X3000
#06008:01020304
$
```

The option `-E` tells `sed` to use extended regular expressions.  The option `-f` tells it to read the program from the file `script.sed`.

The pattern `/^#[0-9]{3}01:/` looks for lines starting with a `#`, followed by 3 digits, `01` and a colon.  The lines between `{` and `}` are executed for each matching line.

The line `:r` creates a label `r` that can be branched to with the `b` or `t` commands.  The `t r` branches to label `r` if there has been a successful `s///` command since the last `t` command.

The `s/:((0|[+%]..)*)[A-Za-z1-9]/:\10/` command searches for the colon followed by any sequence of `0`s or `+..` or `%..` characters (where the dots match any character) and then followed by an alphanumeric character other than `0`.  It replaces that with the colon, the remembered matches, and a `0` to replace the other alphanumeric character.  If you don't omit the `0`, you end up with an infinite loop.

You can also use a command-line script instead of a script file, possibly with several `-e` options (one per line of the script file) or with a single script option and enough semicolons.

Comment: Thank you, managed to get it working. I modified the script slightly to look for only one character after any % or + (%A, +9 etc) and it works perfectly.

Comment: I misread the requirement — sorry — but the fix (removing one of the two dots) is not rocket science.